# warning: cast between incompatible function types al obtener el target de una std::function< >

Tags: c++, gcc

Estoy haciendo una envoltura en C++ sobre un código C; dicho código utiliza el patrón *callback* de la forma habitual: toda función *callback* recibe como argumento un puntero al *objeto* que lanzó la *callback*.

```
struct Object { };
void close( struct Object *obj, void (*callback)( struct Object *sender ) );
```

Para escribir la envoltura, he creado una clase `Wrapper` cuyo único propósito es ocultar un puntero a `struct Object`. Es una clase que cumple con [Standard Layout Type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType), por lo que puede ser pasada como un puntero, simplemente haciendo un moldeado del tipo:

```
struct Wrapper {
  Object *_data;
};
close( reinterpret_cast< Object * >( wrapper ), nullptr );
```

Para adaptarlo a C++, estoy usando `std::function< >` para encapsular las funciones *callback*, lo cual me permite usar *lambdas*, funciones-no-miembro, e incluso punteros a funciones-miembro.

En una parte del código tengo que modelar un puntero a función, que recibe una instancia de mi clase `Wrapper`, a un puntero a función que reciba realmente un `struct Object *`; el punto exacto es:

```
  void (**compatible)( T ) = user.template target< void(*)( T ) >( );
  if( compatible ) {
    std::cout << "Compatible con función-no-miembro.\n";
    return reinterpret_cast< RESULT >( *compatible ); // <- AQUÍ
  }
```

El código mínimo es un poco extenso ... pero es necesario para entender bien el contexto:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct LegacyStruct {
  void *userData;
  // Datos PRIVADOS
  void ( *onClose )( LegacyStruct * );
};

extern "C" void legacyAction( LegacyStruct *st, void (*cb)( struct LegacyStruct * ) ) {
  st->onClose = cb;
}

extern "C" void doLegacyAction( LegacyStruct *st ) {
  if( st->onClose ) { st->onClose( st ); }
}

namespace internal {

struct Wrapper {
  unsigned refs;
  std::function< void( LegacyStruct * ) > callback;
};

} // namespace internal.

class Wrapper {
  union {
    LegacyStruct *_data;
    internal::Wrapper **_wrapper;
  };

  static void Callback( LegacyStruct *cst ) {
    auto &priv = **reinterpret_cast< internal::Wrapper ** >( cst );

    if( priv.callback ) { priv.callback( cst ); }
  }

protected:
  Wrapper( void *ptr ) : _data( static_cast< LegacyStruct * >( ptr ) ) { }

  void setData( void *ptr ) {
    _data = static_cast< LegacyStruct * >( ptr );
  }

  template< typename T, typename C, typename RESULT = void (*)( C * ) >
  static RESULT makeWrapper( void (*globalCB)( C * ), std::function< void( T ) > &user, std::function< void( C * ) > *storage ) {
    // La std::function< > está vacía.
    if( !user ) {
      std::cout << "callback vacío.\n";
      return nullptr;
    }

    // Comprobamos si es compatible con una función-no-miembro.
    {
      void (**compatible)( T ) = user.template target< void(*)( T ) >( );
      if( compatible ) {
        std::cout << "Compatible con función-no-miembro.\n";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        return reinterpret_cast< RESULT >( *compatible ); // <- AQUÍ
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }
    }

    // Hay que usar una lambda para adaptar.
    std::cout << "Usamos lambda adaptadora.\n";
    auto lambda = [user]( C *ptr ) {
      user( T( ptr ) );
    };

    *storage = lambda;
    return globalCB;
  }

public:
  Wrapper( ) : _data( nullptr ) { }

  void *target( ) { return _data; }

  void close( std::function< void( Wrapper ) > cb ) {
    legacyAction( _data, makeWrapper( Callback, cb, &( ( *_wrapper )->callback ) ) );
  }
};

struct Data : public Wrapper {
  Data( ) : Wrapper( ) {
    char *tmp = new char[sizeof( LegacyStruct ) + sizeof( internal::Wrapper )];

    std::fill_n( tmp, sizeof( LegacyStruct ) + sizeof( internal::Wrapper ), 0 );
    reinterpret_cast< LegacyStruct * >( tmp )->userData = tmp + sizeof( LegacyStruct );
    setData( tmp );
  }
};

static void CloseTest( Wrapper sr ) {
  std::cout << "Función 'CloseTest( ), argumento " << sr.target( ) << '\n';
}

int main( ) {
  Data data;

  std::cout << "data: " << data.target( ) << '\n';

  data.close( CloseTest );

  doLegacyAction( reinterpret_cast< LegacyStruct * >( data.target( ) ) );

  return 0;
}
```

<sub>Puede probarse [<kbd>aquí</kbd>](https://tio.run/##tVZdbttGEH7nKaYqYFO0JCev@gNcuUULGEgb281DEhjL5Uohslyyu0unbqAj5BA9QJ9yBN8r6uwfRVJKEQSpBRjL5c7MN983M0taVeMNpbvd97mgvM4YzAnflDLXb4pltN9c14LqvBSEt3fzUmnJCJ6McFFTDVdsQ@jDtXt4HwHcl3kGSa2YvCSazHDn/BxwWSr49fkvv19cPrsOp2JISrHipWIwjLueEhjOou0sitifmkkBg9XA2XB76sJi69soPfKOE5qix2MQ0TH@DFClx8sQfgE0xXiH4bLy6j8Del/5Ou74w932s3mJCcHWhBCkYKoilEEuTDDC0UWg84UkVcWkdVoLlW8Ey0CytZpZxNl0GoSZW4CHtMESKOE8JfStY3BrBDgMOokiyolSvZDo2a6g5/gu82pC42E6DaZJcvfOLc0JE9SAJTqnjsWVB9RHSxsCAUitSzipZH6PaiSJZDZMJZm@o0Tp@dGwsIzBOrEhnQ7GxSRQYJXo7AQDFAOhRlElS82oZtkUn73n2FdxpSU6mIJNPvYpeTg93hGIO20CbqNQ4orpS2vbdugStk4x1y/xOnNYATQrKk40m4N@qJhRFW5G@/WqtX7@4/Xt1Q0G8C2BDbFyBbJXx58pyFvWTT1ONrxMCV/9EMxGx8vvxlbcien3z5zwQU23lJJsWEMAluUV6dssgSn9@DfcE/r4D5k0qn5nIjSmvhdoWWuYz2HQyG3NyskrMZj5g1hANXa0qDlHKt3uNgoAVmWBBZCSAseTyjE2UNxBblLOcCmwIwgYdPnjRzEW5bjIWZHK0gELYDxlyd526JhZgIE9CaqBJnLDtGcm8YdQ5GFAa1JtIdjn28941YV5DKIl4fwb/zVwPK@HfeprCrNK2pnMDN3zMVz8dvv44f@Cte3J@zN5gD9qhioQaaXkpEgzAhWRBEhGKhTESdll91bZivCn3cEMq3dfWHZc@fcLeGlkfm1rvd3iYOVHlZvh4OvPj6umJRbelXvtqQ0d6Ju/qlOe086Uas0mX9@98ZO4govttnfrJrmlKhyj4ZI60r5h2NqLJW1S697D1ueoO0fC0B@h2QhOYnPdh2sChuNla0QPw4QzxPib0IxNTM9l3bmk3EA1ubeIcKjoG9Q50UWFjAr2zj6/VPlfrFz37p4hnEF4cXizDF97hRwlOed3mCX6HcHXeBvBkyD9Yb8cjnyDHwkK31CYi9k5@0xo57e5aKxxm83WNWxkvsH5uldVyeZrqF3/P/lxAqctG0wDq6kumMDSH5hzCkdbU2D4fPpKnNrPKMwRiyEXQRmbhvuCOIhltqfOn1ke84g29pWv0waTv/f7H2lfwnEv1NC78j3yxGSx232ia042ajdGxAt6dvb06W78AssW/@OHoiS7ccUyIpDgfwE)</sub>

Funciona bien en la práctica: los tamaños coinciden, y el contenido es el esperado. Sin embargo, el compilador insiste en avisarme de que tenga cuidado con lo que hago (muy educado él):

```
cast between incompatible function types from void (*)(Wrapper) to void (*)(LegacyStruct*).
```

¿ Hay alguna manera portable (sin depender del compilador) de eliminar este aviso ?

Comment: Lamento mucho no poder darte +5, porque las buenas preguntas de [tag:c++] no abundan.

Comment: En MSVC 2017 no da alarmas, en CLang tampoco.

Comment: Supongo que serán solo el `g++` y el `clang++` ... como dijo una vez @NaCl ... `¡ Esos compiladores están locos !` ¿ Debería eliminar la pregunta ?

Comment: Para qué eliminarla? Responde a una circunstancia que se puede dar, y que a otra persona le puede ayudar...o tranquilizar :)

Comment: @user3733164 No termino de verle la utilidad ... pero en fin, ya está escrita, cuesta mas eliminarla que dejarla :-)

Comment: @Trauma clang habitualmente es el que más se adhiere al estándar C++, seguido de gcc y en último lugar MSVC que va un poco a su aire.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster El MSVC no lo he probado, pero el `g++` es, a veces, **demasiado** *puntilloso*: ¡ Da *warnings* cuando `printf( )` espera un `void *` y recibe un `char *` !